# Android Studio Main Class (Crashlytics, Parse)

Tags: android, parse-platform, crashlytics

I am a fairly new to android development, and I don't understant how the main class works on Android Studio.

I'm trying to make my app have the Crashlytics and Parse services but I'm not sure where to put them. Currently I have the code on the OnCreate method in the Login Class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

    Parse.initialize(this, "CODE", "CODE");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

But I heard that this code should go on the Application Class... That's because the Application Class is always started and its basically the main Class for the app... I am not sure about this, please correct me if I'm wrong.

If that's the case, how can I access the Application Class and where should I put the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a class which should extends the Application , Using this you can initialize the parse installation

```
   public class DemoClass extends Application {
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
         Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

          Parse.initialize(this, "CODE", "CODE");
          ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        }
    }
```

Copy this above code
[image]

Comment: Should I make this class my Launcher class? Or this new class will automatically start by himself when I run the app?

Comment: no just in your package , New> Java Class> Class name

Comment: This seems to work. But i also needed to add on manifest <application
        android:name=".Class name" />